# How do I render a Map data structure in an Ember template?

Tags: ember.js

I use Ember 2.8. There exists [Map data structure](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Map.html) in Ember. It should be iterable. However there's no examples how to enumerate through it and render it.

Assuming that both keys and values in my map are JS objects that have some 'name' set, I tried in Emblem:

```
each myMap.keys as |key|
  p = key.name

each myMap.values as |value|
  p = value.name

/ each myMap as |key, value|    //this one causes build error
/   p = key.name
/   p = value.name
```

None of these syntaxes seem to work and render something more than 'undefined' empty space.

Do any of you know how to render a Map in Ember?

Comment: `EMBER.MAP` is private class.

Comment: @kumkanillam Okay, do you have any suggestions how to render a standard JS Map in Ember then?

Comment: I haven't used. may be you can try `toArray` [source link](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.9.1/packages/ember-metal/lib/map.js#L200)` as usual `each` helper. otherwise you might need to transform that to normal array of object some thing like that to iterate it in template..

Comment: I added my own answer. Thanks for your hint not to use the Ember.Map at all, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was enough to use native JS Map.

My Map ended up using pairs `Object: Array[Object]`.

In Emblem template:

```
each myMap as |value key| // <--- notice the order!
  p {{key.name}}
  p {{key.date}}
  each value as |item| // values from map are arrays so I enumerate through them as well
    p {{item.name}}
    p {{item.details}}
```

In controller:

```
myMap: function() {
  var myMap = new Map();    
  myMap.set(
    {name: 'keyname', date: 'keydate'}, 
    [{name: 'itemname', details: 'itemdetails'}, {name: 'itemname2', etails: 'itemdetails2'}]
  );

  // ... etc set more pairs

  return myMap;
}.property();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [`each-in`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_each-in) helper?

Usage:

```
{{#each-in obj as |key value|}}
  {{key}}:{{value}}<br>
{{/each-in}}
```

Have a look at this [sample demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/215c475316eebdbaf7d31ff89cb97043?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).

Comment: This works for object, but won't work for a map. I figured my own answer, will add it soon.

Comment: Then you need to write a component that yields key value pairs.

Comment: No, I don't actually, turns out a JS Map is iterable enough for Ember to render it with `each`.